# Re-establish git's submodule tracking branch after changes to remote

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project with 4 submodules, as in:

```
$ cat .gitmodules 
[submodule "/submodules/sub1"]
    path = /submodules/sub1
    url = git@my-gitlab-server:namespace/sub1.git
[submodule "/submodules/sub2"]
    path = /submodules/sub2
    url = git@my-gitlab-server:namespace/sub2.git
[submodule "/submodules/sub3"]
    path = /submodules/sub3
    url = git@my-gitlab-server:namespace/sub3.git
[submodule "/submodules/sub4"]
    path = /submodules/sub4
    url = git@my-gitlab-server:namespace/sub4.git
```

When i first cloned my project, it seems that e.g. for `sub2`, the remote tracking branch (and perhaps the project's default was `master`).

I was informed that this changed to `develop`.

So now I have this problem:

```
$ git submodule update --remote
fatal: Needed a single revision
Unable to find current origin/master revision in submodule path '/submodules/sub2'
```

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up setting specific branch (i.e. the new default since it changed) to `.git/config`

```
[submodule "submodules/sub2"]
    url = git@my-gitlab-server:namespace/sub2.git
    active = true
    branch = develop
```

Comment: Note that this setting (`.git/config`) comes from `.gitmodules` in a *new* clone, so you may want to add `branch = develop` there as well. (Once it's been copied to `.git/config` the `.gitmodules` entry is no longer useful *in that clone*, but it's still a trap for *new* clones.)